# Search a file based on a text file's words

Tags: search, vbscript, words

I want to search several words at the same time in a text file.

For example think I want to search these 3 words: Majid,superuser,device

Normally I should search for them one by one, and I can not search all of them at the same time. So I want to search these words at the same time in a text file.

I want to enter those 3 words in a text file, one word per line. Let's name it SearchText. Now I have a Target Text which I want to search those words in it. Let's name it TargetText.

I want to tell an app or something similar to get words from SearchText and find them in TargetText and Highlights them or gives me the find result.

I hope I'm clear. So can anyone hep me?

Comment: And er... What language are we talking in? Please add it as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clear. I think the best option would be Regex.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oFso        : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim srcPath     : SrcPath = oFso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Dim sWordList   : sWordList = ofso.OpenTextFile(oFso.BuildPath(srcPath, "search.txt")).ReadAll()
Dim sTargFile   : sTargFile = ofso.OpenTextFile(oFso.BuildPath(srcPath, "target.txt")).ReadAll()
Dim strWords    : strWords = Join(Split(sWordList, vbCrLf), "|")
Dim oReg        : Set oReg = New RegExp
Dim oDict       : Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'for found words
oDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'case insensitive

With oReg
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "("& strWords &")" ' (word1|word2|word3|etc..)
    'if the words contain some special chars for regex, you may need to escape with \ char
    'see the information below: http://goo.gl/cqGVp
    Dim collFND : Set collFND = oReg.Execute(sTargFile)
    Dim Fnd
    'WScript.Echo String(50, "-")
    For Each Fnd In collFND
        With Fnd
            'WScript.Echo "Word : "& .Value, ", Position: ("& .FirstIndex &","& .Length &")"
            oDict(.Value) = ""
        End With
    Next
    Set collFND = Nothing
    'WScript.Echo String(50, "-"), vbCrLf, "Higlighted Output:", oReg.Replace(sTargFile, "[$1]")
    ofso.CreateTextFile(oFso.BuildPath(srcPath, "foundwords.txt"),True).Write(Join(oDict.Keys, vbCrLf)) 'found words saved
End With
```

Comment: Hi Kul-Tigin, Thanks for your reply again, How to tell this script to save found words in a text file? Also is there any way to skip messages?

Comment: See the comments about special chars in the code. You should escape special chars.

Comment: The page is not loading really :( Can you tell me how to use "\" characters in my words and have a safe finding?

Comment: I can :) Like this \ -> \\ , $ -> \$

Comment: Kul-Tigin you are really great :)) For the last question, think my searching word is Kul, now in target text in first line there is a sentence which contains Kul. I want to highlight the whole sentence and save it in output file, possible?